# how to check whether an element is present in an array using template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

i am trying to find out whether an array contains an element in template toolkit. not sure how? can anyone help?

```
my $var ={
myarray => ['a','c','b','d']
}
```

passed to tt:

now want to check:

```
[% IF ( myarray contains 'a') %]
[% END %]

[% IF ( myarray contains 'e') %]
[% END %]
```

Comment: Same was as anywhere else: Iterate over the elements of the array until you find it or until you run out of elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [grep](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Manual::VMethods#grep)
>
> Returns a list of the items in the list that match a regular expression pattern.

Therefore,

```
[% IF myarray.grep('^e\z').size %]
<p>Hello World</p>
[% END %]
```

Comment: This somehow doesn't work for me as it always returns true, e.g. `[% IF myarray.grep('Q') %]`. Any ideas what could go wrong?

Comment: @user1981275 That is really weird ... I am certain it worked at the time. Using `[% FOR myarray.grep('Q') %]` results in expected behavior, but `IF` is not doing what I think it should.

Comment: @user1981275  The result of `myarray.grep(...)` seems to be an arrayref which will be true even if it points to an empty array. Use `.size` to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

```
myarray = ['17', '177', '166']
value = 16

[% IF myarray.grep('^$value$').size %] # will be true
<p>Hello World</p>
[% END %]

myarray.grep('^$value$') # return ['166']
```

another way

```
[% IF myarray.grep('^$value$').0 == value %] # will be false
<p>Hello World</p>
[% END %]
```